# How to select all the paragraphs between two bullets vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have some bullets in a MS Word Document type `wdListSimpleNumbering`, I am unable to find a way to select all the paragraphs between bullets `u)` and `v)`.

E.g. In the document, I have following bullets;

**u) Company Introduction.**

1st paragraph

2nd paragraph

3rd paragraph

**v) Company Vision**

Now I am looking a way to select the paragraphs between the bullets `u)` and `v)`.

With the following code; I can select the text with bullet `u)` but not sure how to select range up till bullet `v)`. Here is my code:

```
For Each oPara In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs   
    If oPara.Range.ListFormat.ListType = wdListSimpleNumbering And _ 
       oPara.Range.ListFormat.ListString = "u)" Then _     
       oPara.Range.Font.ColorIndex = wdRed 
       oPara.Range.Select ' here I want to select paragraphs 
       Debug.Print (oPara)              
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
Sub TestSelectList()
Dim oPara As Paragraph
Dim bSelected As Boolean
For Each oPara In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    If oPara.Range.ListFormat.ListType = wdListSimpleNumbering And _
            oPara.Range.ListFormat.ListString = "u)" Then ' Make sure to remove underscore for a multiline THEN.
        oPara.Range.Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
        oPara.Range.Select 
        ' Set a flag indicating that you are currently within the desired list item.
        bSelected = True
        Debug.Print (oPara)
    ElseIf bSelected And oPara.Range.ListFormat.ListType <> wdListSimpleNumbering Then
        ' If the flag is positive and the current paragraph is not of the simple list type, include it in the selection.
        Selection.MoveEnd wdParagraph
    ElseIf oPara.Range.ListFormat.ListType = wdListSimpleNumbering Then
        ' Otherwise, if the paragraph is of the simple list type, turn off the flag.
        bSelected = False
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

This doesn't deal with situations where u) is the last item in the list, but I'm not sure what you'd want to do there, or how you'd know.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just want to hide all the text under bullet u). Because I don't want to print it.